# Mongoid == (equals) operator not working as expected

Tags: rspec, mongoid

Sometimes in my tests I compare two user objects:

```
transaction.sender.should == user1
```

And Rspec gives me some output showing that the objects have the same id (and other params) but have a different object id:

```
 Failure/Error: tx.sender.reload.should == @u1.reload
   expected: #<User _id: 5030afb4f8182bb3a9000005, ...>
        got: #<User _id: 5030afb4f8182bb3a9000005, ...> (using ==)
   Diff:#<User:0x007fc0c7e56cf0>.==(#<User:0x007fc0c7ec53f8>) returned false even though the diff between #<User:0x007fc0c7e56cf0> and #<User:0x007fc0c7ec53f8> is empty. Check the implementation of #<User:0x007fc0c7e56cf0>.==.
```

I'm not sure why this is.  I assume the user ids shown on the diff line mean it's a different instance of the object, but Mongoid should check the _id param for equality right?.  I'm using Mongoid 2.4.12.

I thought maybe this would help if the object was out of date but same results:

```
transaction.sender.reload.should == user1.reload
```

I've take to doing this for now but it's worrying me that maybe something else is going on.

```
transaction.sender.id.should == user1.id
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mongoid checks equality by checking the classes are the same first, then checking the ids.

https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/document.rb#L37

If this is failing, I suspect something else is overriding Document#== and I would grep your gems to see if that is the case.